# Matrix of Linear Transformation $T$ with respect to $\beta$ and $\gamma$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I don't quite get what this matrix is doing, and more importantly **what it represents.**

The matrix I'm talking about is the matrix $[T]_\beta ^\gamma$, where $\beta$ and $\gamma$ are bases. What exactly is this matrix, and what does it represent? Any clarification would be tremendously helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If T is a linear transformation from the vector space $V$ to the vector space $W$
$$
T:V\to W \qquad T(v)=w \qquad v \in W \quad w\in W
$$

and $[v]_\beta$ is the representation of $v$ in a basis $\beta=\{b_i\}$ of $V$ and $[w]_\gamma$ is the representation of $w$ in a basis $\gamma=\{c_i\}$ of $W$, than the linear transformation $T$ can be represented by a matrix $[T]_\beta^\gamma$ such that:
$$
[T]_\beta^\gamma [v]_\beta=[w]_\gamma
$$